# Confuse between forms and tables

Tags: php, database, forms, plugin-gravity-forms

I’m get confused between these notion and i don’t know wheres to start from for my project.

I juste want to have the possiblities to get multiple evaluation to person (list of sportif) from the font-end, and get some report with tables and charts. How can i get that the proper way ?

I have bought the gravity forms with wp data table and the addon.

1- I think this way:
I can get a table with my evaluation and a table with my sportif with the foreign key possibilities include in wp data table but how can create the forms to populate that table ?

2 - I think another way :
Create proper tables with mySQL workbench with the relation and export that to my phpadmin.
And find way to populate them with forms and wp data tables

Sorry for my limited english et and my limited developer wordpress capabilities. i try to work on :slight_smile:

thanks for your help,

Comment: Or you may try install page builder such as `Elementor` plugins instead :D

Comment: thx for your reply, i will try